# Keeping reference in an array format

Tags: foreign-key, normalization, referential-integrity

I have a design with an `orders` table and `products` table. Each order can have many products, so 1 order N products.

The default design would be to have something like this:

**orders table**

```
order_id, product_id
```

**Products table**

```
product_id, product_name, value
```

Because each order will have many products I'll have many rows just for one order, e.g.

```
order_id = 1, product_id = 1
order_id = 1, product_id = 2
order_id = 1, product_id = 3
```

I want to save the creation of multiple rows and just store the product_ids in a CSV way like:

```
order_id = 1, product_ids = 1,2,3
```

The table would look like this:

**New updated orders table** the difference being product_ids is now a VARCHAR which will hold many ids separated by commas.

```
order_id, product_ids
```

If so how do I make the relationship? I can't link the product_id to the reference product_ids because it won't match. How do I create that relationship?

What are any other pros and cons or techniques I could use to achieve what I am trying?

Comment: Do **not** store comma separated values in a single column. You typically use an `order_items` table that stores the products used in an order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggested design violates first normal form, which states that every attribute must be atomic. If you store multiple items as a CSV string, you are going to experience many challenges querying it later. You also won't be able to index it efficiently, and of course you won't be able to enforce referential integrity.

Orders are typically stored in an orders table, with attributes pertaining to the order, such as order date, and customer. Order items is a different entity, and should be modeled as an order items table, whose key should be a composite key consisting of order ID and the item identifier.

Follow tried and proven designs, don't try to re-invent the wheel, and definitely don't violate first normal form. There are many good reasons for it.

Comment: Thought so just thought if anyone tried anything similar or had any other ways.